# Where did view columns come from in Postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, information-schema

Suppose that I have a PostgreSQL database and there is a view which looks something like:

```
select foo.id as id, bar.id as bar_id, ...
from foo join bar on foo.bar_id = bar.id;
```

What query can tell me what columns of the view came from what underlying table/column combinations?

The closest that I came is querying `information_schema.view_column_usage`.  That gives me everything except which column in the view is defined.  So I can tell that, for example, `foo.id` and `bar.id` are both used in the view.  But I don't learn whether the `id` column comes from `foo` or `bar`.

(Yes, I can parse the SQL by hand.  But I am trying to automate analyzing a system with many views, many columns, and non-obvious renaming of columns in the views.)

Comment: It is not possible. What about `coalesce(a.id, b.id)`? or `select a.id union select b.id`?

Comment: @JGH Yes, there are complicated examples.  I was hoping to find out which columns are dependent, and then rely on the fact that the selects are generally simple to do the bulk of the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JGH said in his comment, it is easy to come up with views where a view column depends on more than one of the underlying objects.

The view definition itself is stored in the `ev_action` column of the corresponding `pg_rewrite` entry in the form of a parse tree, so you'd have to write C code and dig into the innards of PostgreSQL to deal with it. But be warned: trying to parse the text representation would be even harder.

Comment: Ugh.  Thank you for letting me know where the information is, and that I can't simply look for more information to find it. :-(

Comment: @user9645 That is unrelated. Look in `pg_rewrite`.

Answer (score 1):

I've only ever needed `select * from pg_get_viewdef('view_name')`, but you obviously need something more.

While it doesn't address your question exactly, if you haven't seen the following article from a couple of weeks ago, you'll likely find it interesting:

Abusing Postgresql as a SQL Beautifier

https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/abusing-postgresql-as-an-sql-beautifier/